# I can't upload my html5 project in intel xdk. Error: Unsupported project folder structure

Tags: html, intel-xdk

Here is some error. How to fix it?

[image: error]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions **without** a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Follow the link provided in the dialog box, it will take you to instructions and an explanation of how to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The "see this for more info" link in the dialog box should take you here > https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/faqs/general#www-folder <

Answer (score 0):

create a folder in which you wish to put your project using the file system. in that folder add another folder called www and that is where you will copy your project files of which one of them should be an index.html file. Now you can open up intel xdk and import that project